# How to import data that has a value from other sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, textjoin

I have 2 spreadsheets and I'm trying to get all the items that the QTY is not equal to zero.

Can someone help me, please?

Example. If the items in Spreadsheet 1 is not 0 it will transfer to Spreadsheet 2 in one cell.

Spreadsheet 1

```
*---*----*---*----*
|   | ITEMS  | QTY|
*---*--------*----*
| 1 | BOOK    | 4 |
| 2 | PEN     | 4 |
| 3 | tape    | 0 |
*---*----*--------*
```

Spreadsheet 2

```
+---+---------+
|   |   A     |
+---+---------+
| 1 | BOOK 4  |
|   | PEN  4  |
+---+---------+
```

This formula is the formula.

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10),QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE("URL","SUMMARY!B1:C3")),,2000000))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(
 "ID", "Sheet1!A:B"), 
 "where not Col2 = 0 and Col1 is not null", 0)), , 999^99)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: sir is it possible the output will have a dash ( -)  example. xx -1 ?

Comment: sure: `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(
 "ID", "Sheet53!A:B"), 
 "select Col1,'-',Col2 where not Col2 = 0 and Col1 is not null label '-'''", 0)), , 999^99)))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIMmq.png